# How to spyon an observable property

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, karma-jasmine, behaviorsubject

I would like to unit test an Angular 10 component. In the component's ngOnInit method, this code appears:

```
this.subscriptions.push(
   this.myService.getDataSubject.subscribe((results) => {
      this.data = results;
   }
);
```

Also, in the unit test

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [MyService]
    }).compileComponents();
})
```

My unit test includes

```
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOnProperty(myService, 'getDataSubject', 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockData));
}
```

In the service itself

```
private dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
getDataSubject = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
```

The unit test fails. I've tried multiple variations but cannot get the mockData value to be returned. When writing a unit test for a component that subscribes to a property tied to a BehaviorSubject, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

change

> `beforeEach(() => { spyOnProperty(myService, 'getDataSubject', 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockData)); }`

to

```
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(myService, 'getDataSubject').and.callFake(()=>of(MockData));
}
```

Spy on the function and not on the property

Comment: That change causes the error message, "Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never."

Comment: edited to callFake instead of returnValue. See if that change works

Comment: it still _does not_ work

Answer (score 0):

@PMO1948: your suggestion sent me in the right direction. Here's what I had to do:
Instead of

```
spyOn(myService, 'getDataSubject', 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockData));
```

I called the source function that populates the private BehaviorSubject:

```
myService.requestData().subscribe();
```

Then I spied on that function:

```
spyOn(myService, 'requestData').and.returnValue(of(mockData));
```

So that in my ngOnInit, when the service property is subscribed to the mockData is then returned. At least, that's what I think is happening, and my tests are passing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing topic, but there are two options (and it's definately not using `.and.callFake(()=>of(MockData))`):

To return some mock data from service property, it's better to use SpyObject (to avoid providers mess from your service). Or you can create a fully mocked service with duplicated methods and properties.

In your case, while using SpyObject, to get mocked value you can try this:

```
describe('Using observable property', () => {
  let service: ServiceClassName;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ServiceClassName', [
      // properties and methods list
      'observable$'
    ]);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: ServiceClassName, userValue: serviceSpy}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.inject(ServiceClassName);

    // actual defining mock data
    service.observable$ = of({}); // empty object as mock data
  });

  it('test case', () => {
    service.observable$.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value); // {}
    });
  });
});
```

In fact, you don't need to subscribe to observable property, it's just for example. Also, in case your component subscribed from service `observable$` it would also get this mocked value